# Conditional: “…if he makes a wrong statement.”

Tags: conditionals

> The members of the opposition party in the parliament shout upon the minister if he makes a wrong statement.

According to me: if + simple present clause, + future clause.
So "The members of the opposition party in parliament **will** shout…"

But the book says the only error is ‘upon’ and should be replaced with ‘at’!

[image]

Comment: Did you copy the sentence correctly? Please double check and fix any errors that you may have made. Can you also please tell us the title of the book, and post a link (if there's one) IN your question. Please do not use comments to clarify your post. Good luck!

Comment: I have attached image. Book says jus to replace upon with at

Comment: The book is correct. Either verb tense is fine. It's the preposition that's wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford Can you give me more examples of this structure If +present indefinite, + present indefinite

Comment: It's not really to do with the *if*. The present tense is used to refer to habitual or recurring actions, as in *I take the bus to work* or *I walk the dog in the mornings*. Nothing changes when we put that kind of sentence inside an *if* clause - so *the members... shout* means *more or less every time he makes a wrong statement, they shout at him*, with the idea that this happens quite often. If he was preparing his first speech and was worried about saying something wrong, someone might say *if you make a wrong statement, they will shout at you - but it's OK, just keep your cool*...

Comment: ...in that situation we would be imagining a specific incident in the future, not talking about something that happens on a regular basis. So in your book, there is no problem with the tense - the only issue is that *shout* collocates with *at* not *upon*.

Answer (score 2):

You can say either "shout" or "will shout", both are acceptable.

I think the difference is that "the members of the opposition shout at him if he makes a wrong statement" implies that the minister regularly makes incorrect statements and gets shouted at.

"The members of the opposition will shout at him if he makes a wrong statement" suggests that he hasn't yet made a wrong statement, but the opposition members are prepared to shout at him if he does.